# How to use socketio and ws together on the same port but on different paths

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I started an application using socketio as my websocket library, but now i need to use sharejs which does not support socketio. I would have changed the library but i have come a long way with socketio.

I tried using websocket ws library and it only seems to work when i place socketio and ws on different server ports.

I need to be able to use the same port for both of them. Please how do i do that. I found out that i can place them on different paths but i have not been able to do that successfully. I would really appreciate suggestions or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit odd because express doesn't support proper routing for websocket requests.  The first step is to pass `'destroy upgrade': false` as an option to socket.io.  Without this it will close websocket connections that are on paths it doesn't recognize.

However, closing erroneous websocket connections is still important.  We'll tell `ws` when to do it, so we can accommodate both valid paths.  We'll need to pass a function as the `verifyClient` option to the `ws.Server` constructor.  The function should take arguments `(info, next)`.  You can use `info.req.url` to determine whether this is a path you're handling.  There are 3 cases here:

1. socket.io is handling this path.  Return from the function *without
   calling next*.  This tells `ws` to neither close the connection nor
   try to handle it.
2. ws is handling this path.  Call `next(true)` - this will tell `ws`
   to handle the handshake and then fire a `connection` event.
3. No one is handling this request.  Call `next(false)` - this tells
   `ws` to close the connection.